# Win8/WinRT - How to add line breaks in email body

Tags: email, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my Windows 8 Store app, I have a **Send Email** button on a page and users are able to click it and send us an email for some general enquiries.

I need to pre-load some text in the email body but I can't seem to add line breaks to it. I tried `Environment.NewLine` and `"\r\n"`. None of them works.

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=james.jones@example.com&subject=Hello world&body=Hi," + Environment.NewLine + "Can you please ..."); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

When I run it, I get "Hi,Can you please...". The line break is omitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `"%0d%0a"` as your line break, as in

```
"Hi,%0d%0aCan you please..."
```

That's a URL-encoded ASCII CR/LF sequence.  That works for me for the built-in Mail app but you don't have any particular guarantee that it would work for any arbitrary mail app that the user might install in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're launching a Uri, Uris require that their contents be UrlEncoded / UrlEncodable. In the case of Environment.Newline etc you'd get an invalid Uri.

You can counter this by UrlEncoding the Environment Newline like this:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should consider using a [Share Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh871368%28v=win.10%29.aspx) to share your content to your Mail App. Benefits: Users using your software can share it to other Apps, not only Email.

Comment: I think Share Contract is for different purpose though. In my case I only want the user to send an email back to us. The information could be sensitive and shouldn't be shared. :)

Comment: And I might add that sharing via contract shows the exact same issue, line breaks are just discarded.